# Aggregate function in MS Access causing error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an SQL query like so:

```
SELECT Month(mimos.mimo_date) & "-" & Year(mimos.mimo_date) AS monthyear, 
       Sum(Iif(mimos.amount < 0, mimos.amount, 0))          AS debits, 
       Sum(Iif(mimos.amount > 0, mimos.amount, 0))          AS credits 
FROM   mimos 
GROUP  BY monthyear, 
          debits, 
          credits;
```

This throws the error:

> You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified
>   expression ... as part of an aggregate function. (Error 3122)

I can't seem to solve this despite extensive googling. Has anyone a solution?

Comment: Iif is a thing in access?

Comment: it's actually `iif`. Beautifier capitalised it

Comment: Consider `Format()` to build `monthyear` ...  `Format(mimos.mimo_date, 'mm-yyyy') AS monthyear`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT Month(mimos.mimo_date) & "-" & Year(mimos.mimo_date) AS monthyear, 
       Sum(Iif(mimos.amount < 0, mimos.amount, 0))          AS debits, 
       Sum(Iif(mimos.amount > 0, mimos.amount, 0))          AS credits 
FROM   mimos 
GROUP  BY Month(mimos.mimo_date) & "-" & Year(mimos.mimo_date);
```

You need to aggregate only what is not using aggregate functions. And you can't use an alias as a field on the same query.

Answer (score 0):

*I believe* the issue is that the aliases aren't yet scoped. One approach would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT Month(mimos.mimo_date) & "-" & Year(mimos.mimo_date) AS monthyear, 
       Sum(Iif(mimos.amount < 0, mimos.amount, 0))          AS debits, 
       Sum(Iif(mimos.amount > 0, mimos.amount, 0))          AS credits 
) q
GROUP  BY monthyear, 
          debits, 
          credits;
```